# Why two init methods are called in subclassed Objective-C (UIKit) object in Swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, subclass

I came across this strange behaviour when I subclassed UIBarButtonItem in Swift. I wrote custom init method that called super.init(customView: ...)
The problem was that badgeLabel text never updated, so I started exploring what is going wrong.

First I discovered that two init methods are called, my custom one "init(target: AnyObject, selector: Selector)" and after that the basic one also "init()"

What was really strange is that badgeLabel (constant) block was also executed two times for each of the init methods. So it happened that I displayed a badge label that was created at first init call, but badgeLabel variable was actually holding reference to a label that was created at second init call and never displayed or added to a view.

Not sure if Apple intended this kind of behaviour or its just necessary strangeness/evil for Swift and Objective-C working together. Any ideas of how to elegantly solve this problem?

Here is the code:

```
@objc class MYChatBarButton: UIBarButtonItem {

    let badgeLabel: UILabel = {
        let bl = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 15, 15))
        bl.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        bl.text = "0"
        ...
        return bl
    }()

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    init(target: AnyObject, selector: Selector) {

        let badgeView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(27, 2, 15, 15))
        badgeView.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexString: "ff7d00", andAlpha: 1.0)
        badgeView.layer.cornerRadius = badgeView.frame.size.width/2
        badgeView.userInteractionEnabled = false

        badgeView.addSubview(badgeLabel)

        let button = UIButton.buttonWithType(.Custom) as UIButton
        button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 35, 44)
        button.addTarget(target, action: selector, forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        button.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        button.setImage(UIImage(named: "chat_icon")?.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysTemplate), forState: .Normal)
        button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 7, bottom: 5, right: 0)

        button.addSubview(badgeView)

        super.init(customView: button)

        updateBadge()

    }

    func unreadChatMsgCountDidChange(n: NSNotification) {
        updateBadge()
    }

    func updateBadge() {
        let unwatchedTotal = ...
        badgeLabel.text = "\(unwatchedTotal)"

        if unwatchedTotal > 0 {
            badgeLabel.hidden = false
        } else {
            badgeLabel.hidden = true
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: don't have much time so past only link https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html

Comment: Aha, seems like a lot of rules. Simple solution to my problem would be to move "badgeView.addSubview(badgeLabel)" below super.init method... so this rule is satisfied "An initializer cannot call any instance methods, read the values of any instance properties, or refer to self as a value until after the first phase of initialization is complete"

Comment: :) YES i was about to leave company and going home so did not answer in detail :) but you got the answer Good

Comment: more info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27398668/did-not-understand-process-of-initialize-in-swift-programming

Comment: Thanks, its clear now... although I see problems... still two init methods are called on the same subclass level. For example if I would assign my const badgeLabel inside my 'first' and 'second' init call ... badge label would still be created two times. To me it seems like Apple design flaw.